# Wrong timezone shift after adding a time delta over DST

Tags: python, datetime, dst, pytz, relativedelta

I'm trying to shift a tz-aware timestamp for one month. Since `datetime.timedelta` does not have a month option, package `relativedelta` should be used.

The problem arises when the time point is after the summer DST and the result after the shift will be before summer DST.

For example shift `2022-04-26 07:00:00+02:00` one month back. Expected is `2022-03-26 07:00:00+01:00` However, the result will be `2022-03-26 07:00:00+02:00` (+02:00 instead of +01:00)

Here is a code example:

```
import pytz
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

berlin = pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin")
base_date = berlin.localize(datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 26, 7, 0))
offset = relativedelta(months=1, day=0, 
                       hour=base_date.hour, minute=base_date.minute, 
                       second=base_date.second, microsecond=0)
shifted = base_date - offset

expected = berlin.localize(datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 26, 7, 0))
print("shifted: ", shifted)
print("expected: ", expected)
```

This will print:

```
shifted:  2022-03-26 07:00:00+02:00
expected:  2022-03-26 07:00:00+01:00
```

The result is wrong because the day `2022-03-26 CET` must always have a +1 hour shift.

Comment: Have you tried making your `offset = relativedelta(months=1)`?

Comment: I just tried it, it didn’t work.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried. It won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you use `dateutil` anyway, why not use it for tz handling?

```py
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil

offset = dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)

dt = datetime(2022,4,26,7,tzinfo=dateutil.tz.gettz("Europe/Berlin"))

print(dt, dt-offset)
# 2022-04-26 07:00:00+02:00 2022-03-26 07:00:00+01:00
```

Side note, dateutil semantics are also consistend with the [Python 3.9 way to handle time zone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html).

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you need to use `.astimezone` to get the desired results. As seen below.

```
import pytz
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

berlin = pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin")
base_date = berlin.localize(datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 26, 7, 0))
offset = relativedelta(months=1)
shifted = (base_date - offset).astimezone(berlin)
# shifted = shifted.astimezone(berlin)

expected = berlin.localize(datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 26, 7, 0))
print("base:", base_date)
print("shifted: ", shifted)
print("expected: ", expected)
```

I found this under examples and usage at [PyTz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/)

Comment: This unfortunately won't work. It'll just move the one hour shift to the hour element. In fact, it just tries to apply the tz-shift on the hour to get the tz-shift that matches to expected. So the actual time point is still wrong by one hour.

Comment: Ah, dang I missed that last night… hrm